# Why would a Jenkins REST API call delete a build but still ask for authentication?

Tags: powershell, authentication, jenkins

I'm attempting to use the Jenkins 2.176.2 REST API to create a PowerShell script that deletes builds with certain parameters.  Parameter matching works as expected, but when I attempt to delete the build using preemptive authentication and crumb data

```
$headers = @{'Authorization' = "Basic $credsB64"}
$crumbData = Invoke-RestMethod "http://$serverhost/crumbIssuer/api/json" -Headers $headers -SessionVariable 'session'
$headers.Add($crumbData.crumbRequestField, $crumbData.crumb)
Invoke-WebRequest "http://$serverhost/$projectUrl/$i/doDelete" -WebSession $session -Method Post -Headers $headers
```

I get an error informing me that authentication is required

```
Invoke-WebRequest : Authentication required 
At line:14 char:13
+ $response = Invoke-WebRequest "http://$serverhost/job/Lab/job/BuildRe ...
+             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-WebRequest], WebException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeWebRequestCommand
```

yet the build is deleted anyway.  Why does this happen?

Comment: Always use try/catch and -WhatIf and -Verbose to validate before using with destructive code    
Always use try/catch -Verbose for any destructive code so you have a full record.

Get more error detail

$Error[0] | Format-List -Force

What is on 'At line:14 char:13'.   THis line [$response = Invoke-WebRequest "http://$serverhost/job/Lab/job/BuildRe ...] is not shown in your post at all.

The error is specific.


Use the Trace-Command cmdlet to get even more detail real-time as the code runs.

Comment: @postanote Thank you for your suggestions, but they didn't help here. I found a workaround that I'll post as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Upon looking into this further, I observed by looking at the web traffic with Telerik's Fiddler that Jenkins would
initially respond with a 302 error code and redirect my request to the project page without sending my authentication
header data, thus the server would issue a 403.

I'd imagine PowerShell 7's `Invoke-WebRequest -PreserveAuthorizationOnRedirect` parameter would solve this problem,
but since I am using version 5.1, I created the request myself:

```
try {
    $fullurl = "{0}{1}" -f $build.url.Trim(), "doDelete"
    Write-Host Uri to delete is: $fullurl
    $request = [System.Net.WebRequest]::CreateHttp($fullurl)
    $request.Method = "post"
    $request.Headers.Add($crumbData.crumbRequestField, $crumbData.crumb)
    $request.Headers.Add('Authorization', "Basic $credsB64")
    $request.AllowAutoRedirect = $false
    $response = $request.GetResponse()
} catch {
    Write-Host ("ERROR: The error was '{0}'." -f $_)
} finally {
    if($response -and $response.StatusCode -eq 'Redirect') {
        $response.Close()
        Remove-Variable response
        Write-Host Build $build.displayName was deleted
    }
}
```